# how do I use ember and requirejs together

Tags: ember.js, requirejs, ember-data

I am using require.js for lazy loading files. I added my code in Ember.Route setup method. It's works fine for me unto Ember v1.4. But for Ember 1.5, it's not.

Here is my code:

```
App.BaseRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setup : function(context) {
      require(_rp, function() {
          //.....   
          this._super(context);
      }, function(error){
          //.....
      });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are suffering from [this](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/4301) problem.

There is a blog entry [here](http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/03/30/ember-1-5-0-and-ember-1-6-beta-released.html), describing the problem in the **EVER-PRESENT _SUPER (BREAKING BUGFIX)** section:

> Prior versions of Ember.js used a super mechanism that was un-safe for
>   mixins. If more than one _super was called for a given function name
>   and there was no terminating function, an infinite loop would occur.
>   See #3523 for further discussion.
>
> The solution released in 1.5 fixes this behavior (see #3683), but also
>   breaks the edge-case of using _super out of line. For instance:
>
> doIt: function(){ Ember.run.once(this, this._super); }
>
> Is no longer a supported use of _super. See this jsbin for a live
>   example. If this change impacts you, please comment on #4632.

Answer (score 0):

Following features were added in 1.5

- [FEATURE ember-routing-auto-location]
- [FEATURE ember-routing-bound-action-name]
- [FEATURE ember-routing-inherits-parent-model]

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Maybe something you do on setup now interferes with them? Cannot tell without more code / error description.